# How to calculate market share percent

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query to calculate market share (in %) of Maruti in Dec-2017.

This is the table that needs to be queried.

```
create table Test(month varchar(100), carmaker varchar(100), units_sold integer);
insert into Test(month, carmaker, units_sold) values
('Jan-2012' ,"Maruti" ,101457),
('Jan-2012' ,"Hyundai" ,65423),
('Jan-2012' ,"Honda" ,41316),
('Jan-2012' ,"Tata" ,23340),
('Dec-2017' ,"Maruti", 198023),
('Dec-2017' ,"Hyundai", 140897),
('Dec-2017' ,"Honda" ,76542),
('Dec-2017' ,"Renault", 21734),
('Dec-2017' ,"Tata" ,67521);
```

I have come so far:

```
SELECT Carmaker, (Count(*)/(SELECT units_sold 
FROM Test group by carmaker))*100 as sharepercent
From Test Group By carmaker
```

A little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a sub-query. And you'll want SUM and not COUNT. COUNT will just count number of records, and not total the units sold.

```
SELECT [month]
, (1.00 * a.units_sold) / (SELECT SUM(z.units_sold) FROM Test z WHERE z.[month] = a.[month]) [percentage]
FROM Test a
WHERE [month]= 'Dec-2017'
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to write a query to calculate market share (in %) of Maruti in Dec-2017.

If I understand correctly, you can use window functions to calculate the share for all carmakers:

```
select carmaker, units_sold,
       units_sold * 100.0 / sum(units_sold) over () as percentage
from test
where month = 'Dec-2017';
```

Comment: Gordon, this gives me an error: ERROR 1140 (42000) at line 15: In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'test.Test.carmaker'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by